# How do recurring payments works on pay-pal after completion of time for 1st payment

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I have set up recurring payments with PayPal using IPN successfully, and on any payment I receive back variables and I save them in database.

After completion of a specified time of payment, how would the values update in my database? Is this an automatic process, or do I have to send a request again to get a status indicating whether the user paid or not for this month?

I attach the database values that I save when a user pays me through PayPal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since IPN has been set up during the 1st payment, every time a payment is attempted, IPN will be triggered automatically from PayPal.